# What is the correct notation for a boundary of the cartesian product of a set in $\mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Consider the set $(a,b)\times (c,d]$ in $\mathbb{R^2}$. What is the correct notation for the boundary? Would writing $x=a$ or $x=b$ and $y=c$ or $y=d$ be correct. If not how can I correctly state that?

Answer (score 0):

One way of writing it is 
$$ (\{a,b\})\times [c,d])\cup ([a,b]\times \{c,d\}) $$

Comment: Yes that seems perfect thank you